# Java + Mongo +Morphia - Finding Regex Expression in mongo array

Tags: java, regex, mongodb, morphia

I have a mongo query as follows.

```
db.Course.find( { $and: [{courseCallNo: {$in : [/^ssoapicall1$/i]} }, {clientId :123456 } ] })
```

In my java program , I use [jmkgreen/morphia](https://github.com/jmkgreen/morphia/blob/master/morphia/src/main/java/com/github/jmkgreen/morphia/query/Query.java) as my mongo library. I need to get the **exact match** as above using java.
Following is my code. Please help me out to build this. Thanks.

PS : I guess the problem is , I'm using a string array . I need to create array with regular expressions.

```
 String courseCallNoRegex = "/^"+originalCourseCallNo+"$/i";        
    List<String> courseCallNoList = new ArrayList<String>();
    courseCallNoList.add(courseCallNoRegex);    
    courseCallNoList.add(courseCallNoRegex);    
    List<Course>  courses= getDataStore().createQuery(Course.class).field(Constants.Course.COURSE_CALL_NO).in(courseCallNoList).field(Constants.Course.CLIENT_ID).equal(clientId).asList();
```

Comment: Try using Java rather than JS notation: `"(?i)^"+originalCourseCallNo+"$"; `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The jmkgreen fork is really old. I'd definitely try to get onto the official MongoDB Morphia version, which includes a lot of bugfixes and new features.
2. This... will... be... slow...
   Unless the collection is really small, you'll soon feel the pain of this. If you cannot normalize the data (call a `.toLowerCase()` in the `@PrePersist` on it), I'd duplicate the data into something like `courseCallNoNormalized`. So you can use exact matches, ideally with an index.
3. Have you tried the following?

   ```
   Pattern regexp =
      Pattern.compile("^" + originalCourseCallNo + "$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
   mongoDatastore.find(Course.class)
      .field(Constants.Course.CLIENT_ID).equal(clientId)
      .filter(Constants.Course.COURSE_CALL_NO, regexp).asList();
   ```

Comment: Beware, you may need to escape special symbols in `originalCourseCallNo` with `Pattern.quote(originalCourseCallNo)`.